# how does .so file lookup for symbols?

Tags: c, makefile, undefined-symbol, .so

I have a .so file which has some `extern` function declarations.
Definition of these functions are in a binary to which I am 
linking .so file. But while linking I am getting undefined reference
error.

Is there any way to provide some path in makefile of .so for symbol lookup.

I used `objdump` to list symbols in .so(extern declaration) and .o(actual definition-different directory) , and I see same symbol is there in both places.

```
/homes/uakash/cmd/usr/lib64$ objdump -T libcpld-cmd.so.0 | grep Parent

:::::

0000000000000000      D  *UND*  0000000000000000              _Z29getParentCpldIFDOFromPreviousSt10shared_ptrIN3net74cpld14ParentCpldIFDOEERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE
::::

/homes/uakash/src/usr/sbin/l$ objdump -t cpld_cmd.o | grep Parent

::::
00000000000000d0 g     F .text  0000000000000600  _Z29getParentCpldIFDOFromPreviousSt10shared_ptrIN3net74cpld14ParentCpldIFDOEERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE
::::
```

Comment: you need to link with the library as well. How did you link?

Comment: _"But while linking I am getting undefined reference error."_  It would be most useful if you were to post the link command and the error message verbatim (i.e. copy & paste exactly as they appear in the console).

Comment: Read Drepper's [*How to write shared libraries*](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) paper. It explains that in details

Comment: Please improve your question to show some [MCVE]. Without one, your question is unclear (and both answers have understood it differently). So **edit your question** to show a full (simplified) source code and all the compilation command you are using

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have a misunderstanding on how shared libraries work.  The .so file *contains* the definition, as does the .o file.  One is for dynamic linking, and the other for static linking.  You need to use on or the other, but not both.

Say for example given your shared shared library `libcpld-cmd.so`, and you wish to link it to your code with source `main.c` for example, then:

```
gcc main.c -lcpld-cmd.so -o myprogram
```

The linker will process cpld-cmd.so to resolve symbols, but will not actually link the object code therein - that would be a static link.

When you then run `myprogram`, the library must be available, and the OS loader will *dynamically* link the library code at runtime.

Ref: http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LibraryArchives-StaticAndDynamic.html

If on the other hand you wanted to statically link, you would link `cpld-cmd.o`, and the .so file plays no part and is not required - all the code is statically linked into `myprogram`.

```
gcc main.c cpld-cmd.o -o myprogram
```

Comment: Order of arguments to `gcc` matters a lot

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch : Fixed, I think.  Feel free to edit otherwise.  Thanks.  Note that the command line examples remain minimal - in practice other arguments are likely necessary.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a .so file which has some extern function declarations. Definition of these functions are in a binary to which I am linking .so file. But while linking I am getting undefined reference error.

Then you should link your main program (which is calling [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html), or which is linking with your library) with the `-rdynamic`  flag (and of course the `-ldl` library providing `dlopen`, if you use that).

Read also Drepper's [*How To Write Shared Libraries*](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) paper.